# is there a ruby interface to ms project server?

Tags: ruby, ms-project, project-server

is there a way to connect to ms project server using ruby?
we are using  MS project server 2007

Comment: Is Win32Ole likely to help here?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby can consume web services, and Project Server 2007 exposes an interface (PSI) via web services.

[Using Ruby and HTTParty to consume web services the easy way](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/91/using-ruby-and-httparty-to-consume-web-services-the-easy-way/)

[Consuming SOAP services in Ruby](http://rpheath.com/posts/298-consuming-soap-services-in-ruby)